# Can I install TWRP with stock recovery via apply update from sd card if I change the file to update. Zip? I'm on zte trek 2

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, stock-android

Can I install TWRP using stock recovery and sd card?

Comment: not on stock recovery, but with SP Flash Tool if yours has Mediatek chipset

Comment: Do I have to be rooted and how do I find out what my chip set is? Thanks for answering

Comment: Found out I think it's qualllcom snapdragon

Comment: rooting is recommended because this way the necessary modification (disabling dm-verity) are done already, but root is not required for SP Flash Tool

Comment: Cool thanks any way to root without PC or kingroot? I tried that and kingroot. Don't work.

Comment: If I was rooted I could install TWRP no PC no problem. I don't have access to a computer only wifi

Comment: forget kingroot or other rooting apps, rooting is only possible with unlocked bootloader (forces factory reset) which is only possible with PC. with this app you can figure out chipset http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.andr7e.deviceinfohw

Comment: Ok thanks allot !

Comment: Root is definitely needed for so flash tool

Comment: rooting is a colloquially description for the availbility to execute apps or commands with root privileges (usually a superuser app is installed which manages app permissions based on your choice). flashing partitions (for example twrp custom recovery) does definitely 1) neither require rooting 2) nor won't root your device. for rooting you must install Magisk or SuperSU which can be done via TWRP or by flashing magisk patched boot.img from fastboot (or flash tool)

Comment: I know this. I need to know how to install TWRP without PC or root. Is it even possible?

Comment: if your device is Mediatek you can root with bootless root method on locked bootloader without PC https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3922213&page=101

Comment: (Mediatek) SP Flash Tool / (Qualcomm) QPST is software for PC only

Comment: if you have another rooted device with usb otg support you can install [fastboot for arm](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3722120) and connect two devices with usb otg cable. with this you can unlock bootloader and flash from fastboot without PC

Comment: Thanks for help and sorry to say this is my only device