# Downgrade via stock revovery is it possible and how can I do it with no root or pc

Tags: recovery-mode

Can I downgrade zte trek 2 hd k88 tablet with stock recovery update from sd card option? I'm trying to use kingroot but it won't root my Android 7.1.1 version. Help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I install TWRP with stock recovery via apply update from sd card if I change the file to update. Zip? I'm on zte trek 2](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/222356/can-i-install-twrp-with-stock-recovery-via-apply-update-from-sd-card-if-i-change)

Comment: Well I know you can upgrade via sdcard and stock recovery so I do tthi k my question was that stupid. You told me you didn't need root for sp flash tool but you definitely do need rooted phone to use it. Look I'm not able to access a PC because I'm in prison. Is it possible to do anything? This tablet had TWRP and I flashed SuperSU zip and had it rooted but I foolishly flashed an up date for the original os and it wiped out the whole system and TWRPwith it and reverted back to att  Android version7.1 I m not too smart but I did figure out howto root it with TWRP but now I'm screwed I guess.